# Implement Thread function on PySide application

Tags: python, pyside2

I am currently developing an application PySide2 consisting of several files:

- Main.py which has the class of MainWindow
- ui_main.py which has the class of Ui_MainWindow. It is converted from a ui file generated from QtDesigner.
- functions.py file which has some custom made specific functions I need to run (functions with pandas, pyodbc, py32com etc.)

I have developed the application to where it does exactly what I want (select from drop down menus), select dates from calendar etc. and I need it to run some specific functions from the functions.py file when the Start button is clicked.

The application is freezing when the Start button is clicked (I have not developed the functions with QThread).

The issue is, when I am trying to create a Worker class which should do the job of calling the functions, I am hitting a wall...

For example, one of my functions needs 3 inputs which I am getting from the GUI (Date, Flag, Selection) and while running, I need to have the button to be disabled.

I have not managed yet to success on calling the functions inside a worker class.

## Update:

Well, I have a button on UI_MainWindow class, called pushButton_5.

On the SetupUi function under UI_MainWindow, when the button is clicked, I am calling a function inside UI_MainWindow class:

```
self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.check_connectivity_vert)
```

The function is the below:

```
def check_connectivity_vert(self):
    self.pushButton_5.setEnabled(False)
    ver_ip=self.lineEdit_2.text()
    conn=check_connectivity(ver_ip,5433)
    if conn == 1:
        self.label_9.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(15, 255, 20);") ### GREEN
        self.label_9.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Connection OK!"))
    else:
        self.label_9.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(212, 0, 0);") ### RED
        self.label_9.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Connection Refused..."))
    self.pushButton_5.setEnabled(True)
```

and as seen on the code snip, another function is called (check_connectivity) which is the below:

```
def check_connectivity(ipaddress, port):
   res=0

   c = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   c.settimeout(3)
   try:
       c.connect((ipaddress, port))
   except ConnectionRefusedError:
       res=0
   except TimeoutError:
       res=0
   except:
       res=0
   else:
       res=1
   c.close()

   return res
```

I could not work it out with the worker class and signal to trigger back the working class.

On the main.py file I added the below class:

```
class ThreadClass(QThread):

    any_signal=pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self,parent=None,index=0):
        super(ThreadClass, self).__init__(parent)
        self.index=index
        self.is_running=True
    def run(self):
        ver_ip=self.lineEdit_2.text()
        conn=check_connectivity(ver_ip,5433)
        if conn == 1:
            self.label_9.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(15, 255, 20);") ### GREEN
            self.label_9.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Connection OK!"))
        else:
            self.label_9.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(212, 0, 0);") ### RED
            self.label_9.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Connection Refused..."))
```

And these 2 functions under the MainWindow class:

```
def worker_connectivity_vertica(self,ver_ip):
    print(ver_ip)
    self.thread[1]=ThreadClass(parent=None, index=1)
    self.thread[1].start()
    self.thread[1].any_signal.connect(self.conn_vert)
    self.ui.pushButton_5.setEnabled(False)


def conn_vert(self,ver_ip):
    cnt=ver_ip
    index=self.sender().index
    if index==1:
        print('Index 1',cnt)
```

This did not work at all

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You can disable the button before you make the worker class run. Then you can create a signal in your worker class that is emitted when the run ends. Finally,  you can connect that signal to a method that enables again the button.

Comment: @musicamante posted some code below explaining the workflow

Comment: Edit your question if you want to provide more details, the field you used is for **answers**. Please take some time to [follow the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions, and remember that this is **not** a forum.

Comment: @musicamante Sorry, this is one of my first times posting on Stack Overflow. I have updated the original post.

Comment: @ChristosDiamantis you said "when I am trying to create a Worker class which should do the job of calling the functions, I am hitting a wall". Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: @musicamante Updated with the code I tried to execute